# Create a new dropdown field in admin side custom module and its options should come from another custom module's table?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, admin

I am using Magento1.9.2.4
I want to add 4 field one of them id selectbox.
And I want to load the options for that from another custom module's table,
How can I achieve this.
And yes I want to save the 3 other fields value in other custom table.
Please Suggest how can I do this.

Answer (score 2):

To add dropdown field in admin and get its option from another table-

in your modules `form.php` add code

```
 $fieldset->addField('column_name', 'select', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('module_name')->__('Custom Label'),
            'required' => true,
            'name' => 'column_name',
            'disabled' => true,
            'values' => Mage::getModel('module_name/model_name')->getOptionArray()
        ));
```

Now in your model file add function

```
public function getOptionArray() {
        $Collections = Mage::getModel('another_module_name/another_module_name')->getCollection();

   //it is the collection of your another custom module

    $options = array();
    $options[] = array('label' => 'Please Select', 'value' => '');
    foreach ($Collections as $key => $value) {

        $options[] = array(
            'label' => $value['label_you_want_to_set'],
            'value' => $value['value_you_want_to_set']
        );
    }
    return $options;
}`
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. And Accept it as solution if it works for me.

Comment: My Other Module's fields whose values I want is an text field not select type.